# Convert a JSON_KEYS(specs) result from a MySql query to php array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

From a php script I'm requesting the keys of a JSON field in a MySQL 8++ database (table) using the JSON_KEYS(specs), which works fine.
The result is a string like this $json_keys = '["KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3", "KEY4"]'

Is there a quick way to convert this into a php array ?

Today i'm doing this
$myArray = explode(', ',str_replace(array('[',']','"'), '',$json_keys));
But there must be a better and smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is

$myArray = json_decode ($json_keys)